# xlrd named range not working for Excel 2013 workbooks?

Tags: python, xlrd

I am using Excel 2013, Python 3.4.1 (Anaconda 64-bit) and xlrd 0.9.3.

I made a workbook with the value 34 in cell `B2`, and gave `B2` the name `TestName`.  Then I saved the workbook as a 2013-version (test13.xlsx) and a 97-03 version (test03.xls) file.

I can only get the `xlrd.Name` object to work as expected with the 97-03 version file.

For example:

```py
import xlrd

rb_03 = xlrd.open_workbook("test03.xls")
rb_13 = xlrd.open_workbook("test13.xlsx")
nm_03 = rb_03.name_map.get("TestName".lower())[0]
nm_13 = rb_13.name_map.get("TestName".lower())[0]
print("nm_03.result:", nm_03.result)  # prints: nm_03.result: Operand(kind=oREF, value=[Ref3D(coords=(0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2))], text='Sheet1!$B$2')
print("nm_13.result:", nm_13.result)  # prints: None
print(nm_03.cell())  # prints: number:34.0
print(nm_13.cell())  # fails in line 253 of xlrd/book.py with: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'logfile'
```

Is this a bug? If not, how can I read the value of the cell named `TestName` in test13.xlsx?